# Java bytebuffer convert three bytes to int

Tags: java, integer, byte, endianness

I'm currently working with some little-endian binary data, and I've reached an awkward point where I'm needing to convert odd numbers of bytes into integer values.

Now using the `ByteBuffer` class I'm able to read ints and longs perfectly fine using the `getInt()` `getLong()` functions, which read 4 and 8 bytes respectively.

However, in this example I need to read three bytes and make an int out of them.  I've tried doing `getShort + get()` (2 bytes + 1 byte), but I don't think that's the correct way of doing it.

I'm guessing that I'll need to bit shift the bytes together in order to get the correct int value, but I always get a bit confused over bit shifting.

Also I would have thought that the bytebuffer class would have provided a function for reading odd numbers of bytes, but it seems not.

One way of doing it would be to create a byte[] of three bytes in length, put the three bytes into that, and then wrap a bytebuffer around it, and read an int from that.  But that seems like a lot of extra code.

Any suggestions or advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Post code you´ve tried, not estimations. Please.

Comment: "I always get a bit confused over bit shifting." inhowfar? Shifting 1 bit left is like multiplying by 2, shifting right by one like dividing by 2 (and discarding the remainder). And for example you can make a byte the most significant byte (MSB) of a word by shifting the byte left 8 bits. Adding the least significant byte to the word (or ORing it in) constructs a full word from the two bytes.

Comment: Thanks TheBlastOne, that has helped to clear things in my mind!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get three bytes via

```
byte[] tmp = new byte[3];
byteBuffer.get(tmp);
```

and convert then to `int` via

```
int i = tmp[0] << 16 | tmp[1] << 8 | tmp[2];
```

or

```
int i = tmp[2] << 16 | tmp[1] << 8 | tmp[0];
```

depending on your endianess.

Comment: Thanks Arian, I had a feeling I needed to do that, but now I can see it, I fully understand what it's doing.  Thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score 3):

From the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2):

> Primitive ... byte ... values are 8-bit ... signed two's-complement integers.

[To convert the byte to an "unsigned" byte, you AND it with 255](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10197790/2116188). Thus, the function would be:

```
private static int toInt( byte[] b )
{
    return (b[0] & 255) << 16 | (b[1] & 255) << 8 | (b[2] & 255);
}
```

or

```
private static int toInt( byte[] b )
{
    return (b[2] & 255) << 16 | (b[1] & 255) << 8 | (b[0] & 255);
}
```

depending on your endianess.